# login with thirdparty SNS account strategy

Tags: iphone, ios, security, social-networking, account

I am developing a iOS app, that will require the users to log in with **third-party SNS account**, like facebook, or twitter. However, I want to allocate "native" user id for each users for the benefits of future use.

For example, since each FB user is assigned an `unique ID`, say, 12345678, when this user log in with his/her FB account, I can get this FB id via FB's iOS api, then I can simply add a prefix "`FB`" to this id, stored a local  text file with "`FB12345678`" as content in the i-device.
Then next time the app launches, it simply check the existence of this text file, and if not, pop out a view to require users to `login`, otherwise just use the content, like "`FB12345678`" as keyword to fetch data from my server.

Above is my own thinking. But I think there are some severe problems:

first, is it safe to store a string locally without encryption?

Second, if I use, say in the example, "`FB12345678`" to fetch data, is it safe to transmit via the Internet? 
Chances are this " `FB12345678`" can be easily intercepted, and used to forge the identity of a user.

Lastly, if the user changes his/her FB password, I think my app should require the user to re-authenticate, but from the above strategy, obviously it does not work out.

So could anyone elaborate what is the most commonly used strategy, or algorithm, to enable thirdparty SNS account login? (like Instagram, Parse, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SDKs Provided by different Social Medias. It will maintain the session at your side. It is not proper to save userid on application side and other thing is that in almost all the medias you will require to send the access token and secret to request a data. and the Token Changes so its not good to save it. You can send it with your request and if it will be expired it will automatically ask you for the second time login.
please visit:

www.developers.facebook.com   //for facebook
www.dev.twitter.com           // for twitter

Try following links:

https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine
https://github.com/nov/fb_graph

hope this will help you.